# Question about Popup description in Sharepoint

Tags: popup

I am working for SharePoint for the first time today. The task that I am trying to achieve is I have a table on one of the pages of the SharePoint site, and I want to make it so when I hover over specific items in the table then a pop-up description will pop up. I have no experience coding or anything so I do not even know where to start. Thanks

Comment: They are static values

Comment: Can you update the question with part of the HTML table code? Is that code placed via a web part?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need *some* coding experience to pull that off as there is no out of the box/front-end way to change the popup behaviors. This [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359193/) article has a couple of javascript/non-javascript methods you can use if you are using a table built with HTML/Content Editor. Javascript may have to be used if you have something that has a selector that is harder to get at (a list view or an Excel web part)

Take any CSS or JavaScript you do use and put it inside of a Script web part.